# How to set the session value when the link is clicked?

Tags: php, laravel

When these links are clicked, we have to enter the mobile number and get the confirmation code, and then enter the desired form. that's mean:

Click on the training menu = enter mobile number > enter verification code > open training form.

Click on the shopping menu = enter mobile number > enter verification code > open shopping form.

Click on the services menu = enter mobile number > enter verification code > open services form.

Click on the counseling menu = enter mobile number > enter verification code > open counseling form.

My question is how to set the session value when the link is clicked

[image: register]

app.blade.php

```
@if (Route::has('register'))
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a id="register" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Register
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="register">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('register') }}" {{ session('training') }}>Training</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('register') }}" {{ session('shopping') }}>Shopping</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('register') }}" {{ session('service') }}>Service</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('register') }}" {{ session('counseling') }}>Counseling</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
@endif
```

web.php

```
Route::middleware('training')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/training', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'training'])->name('training');
    Route::get('/training/store', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'trainingStore'])->name('training.store');
});

Route::middleware('shopping')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/shopping', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'shopping'])->name('shopping');
    Route::get('/shopping/store', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'shoppingStore'])->name('shopping.store');
});
```

Middleware/Shopping.php

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->session() == 'shopping') {
        redirect()->route('shopping');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Middleware/Training.php

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->session() == 'training') {
        redirect()->route('training');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Ok, Now how to get session in `training.blade.php` file?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `{{ session('training') }}` where you are. Those helper functions are just going to return session values inside your `<a href...>` anchor tags. Likewise, you're not actually storing any values in the session. The Laravel Docs show how to [set a session value](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#storing-data) using `$request->session()->put('training', 'value');` (which you're not using properly).

Answer (score 0):

In `training.blade.php` you can access the session by

1. Using the `session` helper

   ```
   {{ session('training') }}
   ```
2. `Session` facade

   ```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session; # facade 
   Session::get('training');
   ```

Comment: How to create facade?

Comment: No need to create the facade. its just an import method. built by laravel

Comment: Where should I take the facade? In view, or in controller, or in middleware, or in web.php?